# Macro to iterate through all rows in all columns of a worksheet and compare a cell to copy the row to a text file

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VB excel macro which iterates through all the worksheets in a opened workbook.
In each worksheet, there are few "Y" stored in column K. I want to compare the values in K column to "Y" and if it is equal, then the columns A,B,D,H of the same row should get insert to a text file in the format tab delimited.

This is the code which i have tried. In this code i am inserting only column K to the text file. But I also want to insert the values of A,B,D,H and K column values to the text fil separated by a tab.

Please help me out.

Code which I tried is

```
  Sub Button3_Click()
  Dim fso, myfile, I As Integer, mycount As String, x As String
  Dim curCell As Range
  Dim sh As Worksheet 
  x = "Y"
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set myfile = fso.CreateTextFile("d:\RECP_IMP_COLUMNS.txt", True)
  myfile.WriteLine ("Work Sheet Names are as follows")


    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

      For Each curCell In Sheet4.Range("K1:K300").Cells
       If (curCell.Value = x) Then
        myfile.WriteLine (curCell)
       End If
      Next curCell

    Next

    myfile.Close
  End Sub
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: See How to Ask and Stack Overflow Question Checklist.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Sorry for the same. I am very new to this site. Now I have updated the question with the code I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.Offset()` method of Range object and `vbTab` constant to create tab delimited spaces

The `.Offset(rows, columns)` takes 2 parameters. Number of rows up or down of the current cell. To navigate up you give it a negative value to go down a positive one. Same applies to columns except that you use a negative to move left and a positive to go right.

`vbTab` creates a tab between two objects in the context of

```
"this is " & vbtab & " tab delimited"
```

I have modified your comparison method a bit and added the [StrComp() function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/strcomp-function-HA001228914.aspx). It is more reliable and you can specify the comparison parameters.

Please see [how to compare strings in VBA](http://www.codevba.com/visual-basic-source-code/vb-string/checking_if_two_strings_are_equal.htm) for more details about the `=` operator in string comparison.

I have changed your `Sheet4.Range("K1:K300")` as this is a bit misleading and wrong. You iterate in a loop through all sheets but only used `Sheet4` for each loop. So all your results printed in the text file would be duplicate of `Sheet4` columns K.

the `_` underscore at the end of lines splits code into more lines so you can squeeze in more and make code more readable and clear.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim fso, myfile, I As Integer, mycount As String, x As String
    Dim curCell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    x = "Y"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set myfile = fso.CreateTextFile("d:\RECP_IMP_COLUMNS.txt", True)
    myfile.WriteLine ("Work Sheet Names are as follows")

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each curCell In sh.Range("K1:K300").Cells
            If StrComp(curCell, x, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            myfile.WriteLine curCell.Offset(0, -10) & vbTab & _
                           curCell.Offset(0, -9) & vbTab & _
                           curCell.Offset(0, -7) & vbTab & _
                           curCell.Offset(0, -3) & vbTab & _
                           curCell
            End If
        Next curCell
    Next

    myfile.Close
End Sub
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks @SiddharthRout. You're still [the fastest gun in the west](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) ;)

Comment: This code is working fine. But just wanted to know whether i can compare the string using '=' symbol.?

Comment: @mehow: I usually do not give short answers unless I feel that it's enough information to get the user past the block he/she is facing. I try and delibrately avoid to serve code in a patter as I had mentioned in my comments in the deleted post. :) Also (Just my opinion) I avoid using .Offset when I am working with more than 2 Ranges. I prefer actually typing `Sh.Range("A" & curCell.Row)` than `curCell.Offset(x,y)` This gives me more control. CONTD...

Comment: @mehow: I still use fingers to check what Column does say 15 represent... Guess I am growing old :p Imagine if I am looking at the code after 6 months, I would really have to put in efforts to understand what -10,-9,-7,-3 etc stands for... Like I said it is my presonal preference :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It really helped me a lot to understand more deeper.

Comment: @SiddharthRout hey I was just kidding :) Simply, you just always seem to beat me by seconds (and not only me haha):) I have seen lots of your answers and your blog and I truly think you are of the best users of SO :) I have my own habits too (good and bad) but when answering I kind of judge the OP's experience with VBA and try to give the easiest to understand answers :)